# What is the equivalent of iOS layoutSubviews for UWP?

Tags: ios, layout, uwp, porting

I am porting an iOS app in UWP.

In iOS you can override the method `layoutSubviews` to perform precise layout.

What is the equivalent concept in UWP?

I cannot override `UpdateLayout()`, and I cannot find a method that I can touch when the layout is performed.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some information on what tasks you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

[`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview) is container  manages the content for a rectangular area on the screen within iOS. The equivalent within UWP is [`Panel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel).

`layoutSubviews` will be invoked when frame size changed or add sub view or scrolling scrollview etc.

For UWP `Panel`, it also has the similar event [`LayoutUpdated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.layoutupdated). You could subscribe this event to monitor the layout updated.

Comment: Thank you Nico, but how can I modify the behavior of UpdateLayout()?